# Learn Python the Hard Way - Exercise 36 - if else die function

Tags: python, python-2.7

The second rule for If-Statements [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex36.html), which has me confused states that:

> If this **else** should never run because it doesn't make sense, then you must use a **die** function in the **else** that prints out an error message and dies, just like we did in the last exercise. This will find many errors.

Here's the code from the last exercise:

```
def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def start():
    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == ‘left’:
        bear_room()
    else:
        dead(‘You stumble around the room until you starve.’)
```

Is it essentially saying that you must successfully terminate the program if a condition is not met?

Comment: There is no exception being raised here

Comment: You're right, exit(0) is a successful termination according to the docs. I'll amend my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the idea is:

```
import sys

def die(msg):
  print msg
  sys.exit(1)

if condition:
  # do stuff
else:
  die('This cannot happen!')
```

You could also use an `assert` instead, or raise an exception, or anything else that would fail catastrophically. This helps you validate at runtime that the clause you didn't expect to execute, really didn't run.

IMHO you shouldn't get too hung up on how this `die` is done, exactly. The important point the referred text tries to make is that when you're *sure* some condition is true, you might as well assert it forcefully so that you can catch runtime bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The guide is trying to show you that you can see the `choice` that a user gives when it's something that you don't check for in your `if` statement. If your else looks like:

```
else:
    dead(choice)
```

You will be able to see what the user input that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the syntax only allows for "Left", when the prompt allows entry of anything.  In other words, if I enter "Bob", I will starve.  I should be trapping for anything that isn't appropriate and "die"ing at that point (or helping the user make an appropriate decision).

This is an attempt at teaching error handling and die. You would rewrite it such that you allow accurate entry or die (no exit).  If you don't choose left, there is no other choice even though the prompt states there are two choices.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly expect only `'left'` to be added, a better way of checking for unexpeted input would be

```
  if choice != ‘left’:
     dead(‘You stumble around the room until you starve.’)
  bear_room()
```

That way you still validate that the input is what you expected, but it saves indentation and space for the main logic.